# Parsing JSON response from an HTTP request with Gson in Java

Tags: java, json, http, parsing, gson

I'm trying to read the following json output from a URL

```
{
    "error": false,
    "status": 200,
    "message": "License Key activated successfully.",
    "data": {
        "expire": 1582657054,
        "activation_id": 1519628117,
        "expire_date": "2020-02-25 18:57",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "the_key": "Cqu62al903ICv40am9nM68Y7o9-32",
        "url": "http://domain/my-account/view-license-key/?key=test-32",
        "has_expired": false,
        "status": "active",
        "allow_offline": true,
        "offline_interval": "days",
        "offline_value": 1,
        "downloadable": {
            "name": "v1.1.5",
            "url": "https://domain/product-1.1.5.zip"
        },
        "ctoken": "dsfejk8989"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get both values "status: 200," and "activation_id".

I've tried looking online and parsing. Nothing seems to work. I'm sort of new to the whole json reading.

```java
try {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    String jsonS = "";
    URL url = new URL(link);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.connect();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        jsonS += inputLine;
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonS, JsonObject.class);
    int id = jsonObject.get("status").getAsInt();

    cintout(id);
    cout(link);
    cout(inputLine);
    try {

        if (id == 200)
            return ValidationType.VALID;
        else
            return ValidationType.WRONG_RESPONSE;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException exc) {

        if (id == 200)
            return ValidationType.VALID;
        else
            return ValidationType.WRONG_RESPONSE;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return ValidationType.VALID;
}
```

I've managed to retrieve the status value but not the activation id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `data` object with Gson before you can access its fields:

```
int activation_id = jsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonObject().get("activation_id").getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You used two library for JSON parsing which is not required in this context. Assuming you want to use `Gson`. Remove `JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();`

Now, in your JSON data `activation_id` can be reached at `Root -> data -> activation_id`. Root represents whole JSON object which stored to `jsonObject`. `data` key itself represent an object. Therefore we can reach to `activation_id` by getting `data` key value as an object and then get `activation_id` as int/string.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonS, JsonObject.class);
int id = jsonObject.get("status").getAsInt();
int activationId = jsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonObject().get("activation_id").getAsInt();
```

For more information about json objects: https://www.shapediver.com/blog/json-objects-explained/